# How to change default location for images

Tags: 2013

On publishing pages, you can insert pictures from your computer, then it asks you the destination folder where you want to put them

In my case it shows  a Document Library, site assets and Image library.

Is there anyway that the Image library is the default? and that the user does not have to select?

Comment: are you using custom master page?

Comment: 2013 Server or online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a JavaScript/Jquery approach:

Add the following CSS to your custom css file.

```
tr[id$='SelectListSection']{display: none;}
```

In your custom JS file add:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  autoSelectDestinationLibrary();
});

function autoSelectDestinationLibrary() {
 if (document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf('upload.aspx') != -1) {
    var ddDestLib = $("select[id$='AvailableDocLibs']");
    if (ddDestLib.length > 0) {
        $("select[id$='AvailableDocLibs'] option:contains('Images')").prop('selected', true);
        $("tr[id$='SelectListSection']").fadeIn('medium');
    }
 }
}
```

If you're on SP2013 on-prem you can:

- create your own 'upload.aspx' and add the necessary logic.
- Use customActions to tie it to particular list/library/content type.